# data base or text file and excel file in Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary

if you have some fixed data  in Django, for example, ten rows and 5 columns.
Is it better to create a  database for it and read it from the database, or is it not good and it is better to create a dictionary and read the data from the dictionary?
In terms of speed and logic and ...

If the database is not a good choice, should I write the data as a dictionary in View Django or inside a text file or inside an Excel file?

Whichever method is better, please explain why.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon the application.. but if there is doubt, create a model for it and put it in the database.  And here's why I say that:

1. If your data needs to be changed, or if you want to view it, you can easily do so in the Django Admin app.
2. If your applications contains models which relate to this data, you can use a foreign key to reference it, rather than replicating it or using references that aren't enforced by the database.
3. It makes it much easier to do queries on your whole database if everything is in the database.  For example, let's say that you have a table of "houses" and each house has a "color".. but you've stored the list of color names in a dictionary outside the database.  Now you want a list of houses that are "Bright Blue".  First you have to look in your dictionary to find the id of the color "Bright Blue", then you have to do your database lookup using the id you found.  It takes something that would normally be a very simple one-line query in Django and makes it much harder.
4. By the same logic, if you wanted a list of houses along with their color, this would be a very simple query if done entirely in the database but is extra work if you keep some data elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, a few questions: 1- My app does not have another model, does not just making this one model create additional costs? 2- Is not the speed of reading from a dictionary or text file faster than a database?

Comment: Reading from a dictionary is much faster than the database.  But, unless your application gets lots of requests (thousands per minute), you wouldn't notice much if any difference.  BUT, sure.. if you have a super simple application that has absolutely no other need for a database, then don't use one.  It really depends on the needs of your application.  Reading the data in from a csv file is also a reasonable way to do it.